# cannot import name 'CppEGLRenderer' from 'lib.egl_renderer'

Tags: python, x11, egl

I connect to destination machine (ada) like this:

```
connect to globalprotect vpn
ssh -X machine 1
(machine 1) : ssh -X ada
```

my own machine is Ubuntu and the other two I ssh to also same version of Ubuntu. How can I fix this error?

```
(gdrnpp) mona@ada:~/gdrnpp_bop2022$ ./core/gdrn_modeling/train_gdrn.sh configs/gdrn/ycbv/convnext_a6_AugCosyAAEGray_BG05_mlL1_DMask_amodalClipBox_classAware_ycbv.py 0
++ dirname ./core/gdrn_modeling/train_gdrn.sh
+ this_dir=./core/gdrn_modeling
+ CFG=configs/gdrn/ycbv/convnext_a6_AugCosyAAEGray_BG05_mlL1_DMask_amodalClipBox_classAware_ycbv.py
+ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
+ IFS=,
+ read -ra GPUS
+ NGPU=1
+ echo 'use gpu ids: 0 num gpus: 1'
use gpu ids: 0 num gpus: 1
+ NCCL_DEBUG=INFO
+ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
+ MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
+ PYTHONPATH=./core/gdrn_modeling/../..:/home/mona/realsense-ros/install/realsense2_camera_msgs/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages:/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages:/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
+ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
+ python ./core/gdrn_modeling/main_gdrn.py --config-file configs/gdrn/ycbv/convnext_a6_AugCosyAAEGray_BG05_mlL1_DMask_amodalClipBox_classAware_ycbv.py --num-gpus 1
/home/mona/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mmcv/__init__.py:20: UserWarning: On January 1, 2023, MMCV will release v2.0.0, in which it will remove components related to the training process and add a data transformation module. In addition, it will rename the package names mmcv to mmcv-lite and mmcv-full to mmcv. See https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv/blob/master/docs/en/compatibility.md for more details.
  warnings.warn(
You requested to import horovod which is missing or not supported for your OS.
/home/mona/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mmcv/device/npu/data_parallel.py:22: UserWarning: Torchaudio's I/O functions now support par-call bakcend dispatch. Importing backend implementation directly is no longer guaranteed to work. Please use `backend` keyword with load/save/info function, instead of calling the udnerlying implementation directly.
  if hasattr(sys.modules[m], '_check_balance'):
/home/mona/gdrnpp_bop2022/core/gdrn_modeling/../../lib/pysixd/misc.py:586: NumbaDeprecationWarning: The 'nopython' keyword argument was not supplied to the 'numba.jit' decorator. The implicit default value for this argument is currently False, but it will be changed to True in Numba 0.59.0. See https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit for details.
  def get_obj_im_c(K, t):
/home/mona/gdrnpp_bop2022/core/gdrn_modeling/../../lib/pysixd/misc.py:765: NumbaDeprecationWarning: The 'nopython' keyword argument was not supplied to the 'numba.jit' decorator. The implicit default value for this argument is currently False, but it will be changed to True in Numba 0.59.0. See https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit for details.
  def compute_2d_bbox_xyxy_from_pose(points, pose, K, width=640, height=480, clip=False):
/home/mona/gdrnpp_bop2022/core/gdrn_modeling/../../lib/pysixd/misc.py:793: NumbaDeprecationWarning: The 'nopython' keyword argument was not supplied to the 'numba.jit' decorator. The implicit default value for this argument is currently False, but it will be changed to True in Numba 0.59.0. See https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit for details.
  def compute_2d_bbox_xyxy_from_pose_v2(points, pose, K, width=640, height=480, clip=False):
/home/mona/gdrnpp_bop2022/core/gdrn_modeling/../../lib/pysixd/misc.py:822: NumbaDeprecationWarning: The 'nopython' keyword argument was not supplied to the 'numba.jit' decorator. The implicit default value for this argument is currently False, but it will be changed to True in Numba 0.59.0. See https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit for details.
  def compute_2d_bbox_xywh_from_pose(points, pose, K, width=640, height=480, clip=False):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mona/gdrnpp_bop2022/./core/gdrn_modeling/main_gdrn.py", line 39, in <module>
    from core.gdrn_modeling.engine.engine_utils import get_renderer
  File "/home/mona/gdrnpp_bop2022/core/gdrn_modeling/../../core/gdrn_modeling/engine/engine_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from lib.egl_renderer.egl_renderer_v3 import EGLRenderer
  File "/home/mona/gdrnpp_bop2022/core/gdrn_modeling/../../lib/egl_renderer/egl_renderer_v3.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import CppEGLRenderer
ImportError: cannot import name 'CppEGLRenderer' from 'lib.egl_renderer' (/home/mona/gdrnpp_bop2022/core/gdrn_modeling/../../lib/egl_renderer/__init__.py)
```

I have:

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ uname -a
Linux ada 6.2.0-37-generic #38~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov  2 18:01:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) mona@ada:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
(base) mona@ada:~$ nvidia-smi
Fri Dec 22 14:24:54 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.104.12             Driver Version: 535.104.12   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX 6000 Ada Gene...    On  | 00000000:52:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 31%   60C    P2              71W / 300W |   4213MiB / 49140MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2310      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          913MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2535      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         80MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3040      G   ...AAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       43MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     26577      G   /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird             19MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    151053      G   ...AAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAA== --shared-files      102MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    862586      C   python                                      918MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    863180      C   python                                      730MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    864122      C   python                                      730MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    901572    C+G   ./blender                                   411MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A   1014271      G   ...sion,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess       51MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A   1023738      G   meshlab                                      13MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A   3651908      G   ...irefox/3358/usr/lib/firefox/firefox       68MiB |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: error may suggests that you may have to use `apt` to install some C/C++ library for `EGL`. Maybe `mesa`, maybe `glfw` or maybe `libegl`. You may try `apt search egl` to search libraries for `EGL` - ie. `libegl1`, `libegl1-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(gdrnpp) mona@ada:~/gdrnpp_bop2022$ cd lib/egl_renderer/
(gdrnpp) mona@ada:~/gdrnpp_bop2022/lib/egl_renderer$ pip install -e .
```